# to call javascript function in index.html from 'didReceiveRemoteNotification' function

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios, cordova

I am using cordova 2.1.0 to create IOS app. How can i call a javascript function from 'didReceiveRemoteNotification' function which is invoked by the delegate when a notification is received by the device.

The function definition is as under:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{
 ......
  Call_to_js_function(); // in index .html 
}
```

How can i call this js function. Please also mention if any parameters to 'didReceiveRemoteNotification' function are to be changed.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create Plugin
2. Call plugin function from 'didReceiveRemoteNotification'
3. Use 'writeJavascript' method of base class CDVPlugin

**Check [PushNotification Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/PushNotification) for IOS**

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/PushNotification

Comment: My question is a bit general, if i have to call a js function(in index.html) from objective-c(from 'didReceiveRemoteNotification' method), what should i do. Your answer is related to PushNotification plugin. Is there anything other than plugin, i can do. By the way, I could not understand the utility of the plugin.

Comment: Plugin give you the way to communicate between JavaScript and native code. I can run native code from JavaScript by calling 'cordova.exec' and receive callbacks or throw events to JavaScript.(look in PushNotification.js)